# Access Constructor variables from another class c#

Tags: c#

I have a class called (calcDisplay) where I want to calculate values with variables that are in different classes such as the class (Semester). How do I access WEEKS from semester class and use it in calcDisplay class with a method.

calcDisplay class:

```
namespace TimeManagementClassLibrary
{
    public  class CalcDisplay
    {
        public static double CalculateStudyHours(int credits, int classHours, int weeks)
        {
        
            return (credits * 10 / weeks) - classHours;
            
        }
```

Semester class: (I want to access WEEKS in this class and use it in calcDisplay class)

```
namespace TimeManagementClassLibrary
{
    public class Semester
    {
        public int Weeks { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        public Semester()
        {
        }

        public Semester(int weeks, DateTime startdate)
        {
            Weeks = weeks;
            StartDate = startdate;
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know the solution to this and also if there's a better approach to this.

Comment: How did you instantiate the `Semester` class?

Comment: You can create  var calc = new CalcDisplay(), and then call your method calc.CalculateStudyHours(). Could add more specific information what you would like to do

Comment: so to access a member value you have to pass the class in, either by parameter, injector property or constructor or by making a semester extension with the same parameters use the other class, but please what are the relation between the classes, what is your usage pattern?

Comment: I have a WPF class where I create the semester object and pass in variable values (weeks and date) from user input, I want to access these variables in the CalcDisplay class where i can perform calculations with them along with other values from another class.

Answer (score 1):

Either you can pass semester.Weeks as a parameter (**first example**) or you can create Semester object inside CalcDisplay (**second example**) but you need to remove static keyword as you cannot use non static field inside a static class/function.

```
namespace TimeManagementClassLibrary
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Semester semester = new Semester(10, DateTime.Today.AddDays(10));
            CalcDisplay.CalculateStudyHours(3, 15, semester.Weeks);
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
    public class CalcDisplay
    {
        public static double CalculateStudyHours(int credits, int classHours, int weeks)
        {
            return (credits * 10 / weeks) - classHours;
        }
    }
    public class Semester
    {
        public int Weeks { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        public Semester(int weeks, DateTime startdate)
        {
            Weeks = weeks;
            StartDate = startdate;
        }
    }
}
```

Second Example:

```
namespace TimeManagementClassLibrary
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CalcDisplay calcDisplay = new CalcDisplay();
            calcDisplay.CalculateStudyHours(3, 15);
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
    public class CalcDisplay
    {
        Semester semester = new Semester(10, DateTime.Today.AddDays(10));
        public double CalculateStudyHours(int credits, int classHours)
        {
            return (credits * 10 / semester.Weeks) - classHours;
        }
    }
    public class Semester
    {
        public int Weeks { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        public Semester(int weeks, DateTime startdate)
        {
            Weeks = weeks;
            StartDate = startdate;
        }
    }
}
```